# Ripple effect on clicking linear layout on android

Tags: android, ripple

I have a linear layout with a text field inside it. I would like to highlight the layout when a user clicks on it.

I have a drawable background for the same as below and it works fine on Android 4.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/layout_pressed"   />
</selector>
```

The layout_pressed defines a shape with the highlight color.

For lollipop devices, I want a ripple effect added as well. I created the same layout background file under v21 directory with the following contents.

```
<ripple
android:color="@color/gray"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@color/gray" />
</ripple>
```

On Android 5, this creates a layout with a gray color background. With the ripple, my layout's background color takes the android:color of the ripple. It does add a ripple effect but I don't want the original background color of my layout to change.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks,
Sudha